# Xamarin media plugin get android image path

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.forms

I am using the media plugin for xamarin forms (by james montemagno) and the actual taking of the picture and storing it works fine, I have debugged the creation of the image on the emulator and it is stored in

```
/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/{APPNAME}.Android/files/Pictures/{DIRECTORYNAME}/{IMAGENAME}
```

however in my app it will get a list of file names from an API I want to check if the image exists in that folder.

The following works fine on IOS

```
var documentsDirectory = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);
string jpgFilename = System.IO.Path.Combine(documentsDirectory, App.IMAGE_FOLDER_NAME);
jpgFilename = System.IO.Path.Combine(jpgFilename, name);
```

I have tried the 2 following methods for getting it on android but both are incorrect

```
var documentsDirectory = System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);
string jpgFilename = System.IO.Path.Combine(documentsDirectory, App.IMAGE_FOLDER_NAME);
jpgFilename = System.IO.Path.Combine(jpgFilename, name);
Java.IO.File dir = Android.OS.Environment.GetExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Android.OS.Environment.DataDirectory + "/" + App.IMAGE_FOLDER_NAME + "/" + name);
```

dir ends up as 
/storage/emulated/0/data/{DIRECTORY}/{IMAGENAME}

jpgFileName ends up as /data/data/{APPNAME}.Android/files/{DIRECTORYNAME}/{IMAGENAME}

I dont want to hardcode anything in the paths but neither of these are right. I could not find anything in the GIT documentation for getting the file path except by looking at the path of the file created when taking a picture

Comment: I remember trying to do this a while ago. I think I gave up on reproducing the default save location. Instead I created my own reproducable folder and you can supply that to the Media Plugin options so the image will be saved there.

Comment: @GeraldVersluis I have tried looking for a way to do this but the only options on the media plugin seems to be directory which just appends another folder on the end which I am already using rather than defining a full path to save to. The only way I can see of doing it would be to save the image a second time then remove the original  which I would like to avoid if possible

Answer (score 4):

### The problem

I had the same kind of issue with Xamarin Media Plugin. For me, the problem is:

- we don't really know where the plugin save the picture on android.

After reading all documentation I found, I just noted this:

> ... When your user takes a photo **it will still store temporary data**, but also if needed make a copy to the public gallery (based on platform). In the MediaFile you will now see a AlbumPath that you can query as well.

(*from: [Github plugin page](https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/mediaplugin)*)

- so you can save your photo to your phone gallery (it will be public) but the path is known.
- and we don't know what means "store the temporary data".

### Solution

After investigating on how/where an app can store data, I found where the plugin stores photos on Android >> **so I can generate back the full file names**

In your Android app, the base path you are looking for is:

```
var basePath = Android.App.Application.Context.GetExternalFilesDir(null).AbsolutePath
```

It references your **app's external private folder**. It looks like that:

```
/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.mycompany.myapp/files
```

So finally to get your full file's path:

```
var fullPath = basePath + {DIRECTORYNAME} + {FILENAME};
```

I suggest you **to make a dependency service**, for instance 'ILocalFileService', that will expose this 'base path' property.

Please let me know if it works for you !

Comment: Exactly my same problem, I don't know what it means by 'it will still store temporary data'

Answer (score 0):

I resolved a similar problem. I wanted to collect all files for my app in a folder visible to all users.

```
var documentsDirectory = Android.OS.Environment.GetExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
                                                Android.OS.Environment.DirectoryDocuments);
```

[image: FileManager under Android]

If you want to create `Directory`, add to your class `using System.IO;` and you have the same functions in a normal .NET application.

```
if (!Directory.Exists(path))
    Directory.CreateDirectory(path);
```

If you want to create files or directory, you can use `PCLStorage`.

```
public async Task<bool> CreateFileAsync(string name, string context)
{
    // get hold of the file system
    IFolder folder = FileSystem.Current.LocalStorage;

    // create a file, overwriting any existing file
    IFile file = await folder.CreateFileAsync(name, 
                                              CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);

    // populate the file with some text
    await file.WriteAllTextAsync(context);

    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

to get the private path 
var privatePath = file.Path;

to get the public Album path 
var publicAlbumPath = file.AlbumPath;

se the documentation here https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/MediaPlugin